# Logic apps: How to add root node in JSON variable?

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to do the following:

```
@xml(json(concat('\\"rootnode\\":',variables('TestJSON'))))
```

However the error I am getting is :

> InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in
> action 'Set_XXXXXXX' inputs at line '1' and column '1873': 'The
> template language function 'json' parameter is not valid. The provided
> value '\"rootnode\":..........  cannot be parsed: 'Unexpected
> character encountered while parsing value: \. Path '', line 0,
> position 0.'.

Looks like escape character is not working in Logic Apps? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this expression:

```
xml(json(concat('{"rootnode":',variables('TestJSON'), '}')))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Frank. It worked. Looks like adding "{" and "}" is what I missed. Also, can you tell if Logic App doesn't support \ escape chars?

Comment: As far as I know, `Azure logic app` should support escaping (not tested). As for the example you provided, adding `"` in `'` does not need to be escaped.